# Is it good to use jQuery AJAX with traditional true?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

First, I don't know what traditional means in Ajax setting,
Second, is there any case we need set it to be true in ASP MVC?

Based on the name, I believe it's going to be depreciated soon? Isn't it?

Comment: Don't deface your posts please.

Comment: Please don't un-accept your answer just to delete the question. Instead, read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Comment: then how to remove it? or i can not??

Comment: Did you visit the link? It explains everything.

Comment: Or even the linked question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: thanks, asked moderator to do it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**jQuery API documentation**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

> **traditional**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Set this to true if you wish to use the
> traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Let's have a look below, `tranditional` flag changes the way how parameters are sent to the server

**For PHP developer**

```
$.ajax(url, {
   data : { a : [1,2,3] },
   traditional : false
});
// `data` are sent as "a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3"
```

**For ASP.NET MVC developer**

```
$.ajax(url, {
   data : { a : [1,2,3] },
   traditional : true
});

// `data` are sent as "a=1&a=2&a=3"
```

As you can see, it is important to set `traditional` flag depending on your server side language.

So I guess, it won't be deprecated anytime in near future.

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the $.param() method no longer uses jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional as its default setting and will default to false. For best compatibility across versions, call $.param() with an explicit value for the second argument and do not use defaults.`

Comment: i use `$.param()` for demo purpose only. Whereas in implementation, you'll need to set `traditional` explicitly when calling `$.ajax`

Comment: That was a copy-paste from the link you provided to make more emphasis on your last line about deprecation

Comment: server side language matters, but I don't think that's the main reason for it. I am not using jQuery.param, I am thinking about the usage of it in $.ajax

Comment: ASP.NET MVC won't bind `a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3` to `int[] a` , maybe my example is misleading, i'll update it