# What´s the difference between traditional:true option and false in Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-ajax

All of this is for discard a problem with a MVC controller.

This is the code of the ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            //tipo de transferencia
            type: "POST",
            //dato a enviar
            dataType: 'Json',
            traditional:true,
            //enviar variable previamente formada contiene la estructura del modelo
            data:data,

            //liga previamente asignada esta liga contiene  la ruta controlador-metodo
            url: url,
```

Notice the traditional:true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**jQuery API documentation**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

> **traditional**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Set this to true if you wish to use the
> traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

The `traditional` property changes the way how parameters are sent to the server. As of jQuery 1.8, it is defaulted to false.

**For ASP.NET MVC developer**

```
$.ajax(url, {
   data : { a : [1,2,3] },
   traditional : true
}));

// `data` are sent as "a=1&a=2&a=3"
```

If `traditional` was set to `false` the data would be sent as `a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&a%5B%5D=3`

Answer adapted from [neverever from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31152304/6261724)