# How to pass a complex C# object using FromQuery

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my client side code, I have an object like this:

```
{
  "selectedItems": [
    4016,
    3937
  ],
  "selectedStatuses": [],
  "search": "foo"
}
```

Which I'd like to map onto a C# DTO

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public List<int> SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedStatuses { get; set; }
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

But it's used in a GET query, so I can't pass it via `FromBody` only `FromQuery`. There are already basic parameters in the controller action:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/filter/{typeId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredData([FromRoute]int id, 
    [FromRoute]int typeId,
    [FromQuery]FilterModel filters = null)
```

Client-side, I'm building this query using $http in Angular. How do I set up my $http call to create my filters object as a query string?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, your query names need to be same as they would be if they were input names being posted, i.e. `filters.SelectedItems[]` (repeated for each item in the list), `filters.SelectedStatuses[]` (repeated for each item in the list), and `filters.Search`. For example:

```
?filters.SelectedItems[]=item1&filters.SelectedItems[]=item2&filters.SelectedItems[]=item3&filters.SelectedStatuses[]=status1&filters.SelectedStatuses[]=status2&filters.SelectedStatuses[]=status3&filters.Search=keyword
```

Note: there's a fair bit of leeway here, but eventually, you will hit a max request length limit. You shouldn't have any problems for the most part, but if you start selecting like 100s of things, you're likely going to need a different plan.

FWIW, you can always just use a post, especially if you're doing this via AJAX, as it would be seamless to the user, either way.

Comment: Yes, but `filters.SelectedJobs[]`, not just `selectedJobs`. You need to match the param and property names exactly or it won't bind.

Comment: yes, sorry. Deleted my query when you updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a related source I've found helpful: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax, a simple way is to add `traditional:true` to use the traditional style of param serialization.Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081486/what%C2%B4s-the-difference-between-traditionaltrue-option-and-false-in-ajax-call?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
var data =
        {
            "selectedItems": [
                4016,
                3937
            ],
            "selectedStatuses": [12, 34],
            "search": "foo"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "your url", //directly like /Home/{id}/filter/{typeId}              
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
```