# Error "Incorrect Content Type" when sending parameter in ajax datatable to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I obtain table data from database via AJAX request. And I need to change data parameter in AJAX request when button is click and refresh the table.

Here's my button handler code:

```
$("#btnView").on('click', function () {
        var dt = $("#dtStart").val();
        var cn = $("#txtConn").val();
        var sendData = JSON.stringify({ dt: dt, cn: cn });
        //setMyNewParameters(sendData);
        //$('#tblConnoteList').DataTable().ajax.reload()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Order/myList?param=" + sendData,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true
        })
            .done(function (data) {

                var table = $('#tblConn').DataTable({
                    data: data.data,
                    destroy: true,
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "ConnDate" },
                        { "data": "ConnNumber" },
                        { "data": "Customer" }
                    ],
                    "ordering": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "searching": false, "bPaginate": false
                });
            });

    });
```

and code-behind:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string param)
{
        var requestFormData = Request.Form;
        lstConnoteData = ConnoteData();
        List<CoreGPS.Models.Bagging> lstItems = GetData();

        var listItems = ProcessCollection(lstConnoteData, requestFormData);

        // Custom response to bind information in client side
        dynamic response = new
        {
            data = listItems,
            draw = requestFormData["draw"],
            recordsFiltered = listItems.Count,
            recordsTotal = listItems.Count
        };

        return new OkObjectResult(response);
}
```

I always get an error

> Incorrect Content Type

[error in code-behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OMH2.png)

Is there any solution to send parameter in ajax and apply the response in datatable?

Comment: the parameters for post needs to go in body like: `url: "/Order/myList", body { param: sendData }`

Comment: i already tried add data: JSON.stringify(data) but result is the same always incorrect content type

Comment: Do you need tradition set to true? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152130/is-it-good-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-traditional-true

Comment: @pixelda not exactly , all i need is to send parameter from ajax to POST method and apply return  into datatable -> $("#mytable").datatable(), i cant send any paramter (querystring or body) it always get me error Incorrect content type, see my snap https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OMH2.png, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check settings options that are available for AJAX requests :

**contentType** :

This is the content type of the request you are making. The default is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

**dataType**:

This is the type of data you expect to receive back. Accepted values are text, xml, json, script, html jsonp. If you do not provide a value, jQuery will examine the MIME type of the response and base its decision on that.

**Solution1:**

The default `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` . So you can use :

```
$("#btnView").on('click', function () {
            var dt = "A";
            var cn = "B";
            var sendData = { dt: dt, cn: cn } ;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/myList?param=" + "whatever",
                data: sendData,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true
            })
```

And server side you can get value from `var requestFormData = Request.Form;`

**Solution2:**
If you want to post JSON ,you can use `JSON.stringify` and set `contentType: "application/json"`:

```
    $("#btnView").on('click', function () {
            var dt = "A";
            var cn = "B";
            var sendData = { dt: dt, cn: cn } ;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/myList",
                data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                contentType: "application/json", 
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true
            })
```

And on server side try extracting your params into a separate DTO class :

```
public class ParentDTO
{
      public string dt { get; set; }
      public string cn { get; set; }
}
```

And accept parameters :

```
public IActionResult myList([FromBody] ParentDTO parentDTO)
{
    ... 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look on following notes,

in ajax call, set the content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and remove the JSON.stringify from data.

```
var searchObj = {
                FirstName: $('#txtFirstName').val(),
                LicenseNumber: $('#txtLicenseNumber').val(),
                PhoneNumber: $('#txtPhoneNumber').val()
            }



   $("#customerData").DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Customer/CustomerSearch",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "data": searchObj,
                    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                }
            });
```

and in the controller method,removed the  [frombody]

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CustomerSearch(CustomerSearchInput searchObj)
        { 
         // here your code
        }
```